# Facebook playing hide and seek

Tags: status-bydesign, sharing, bug

Is Stack Overflow talking about their period? I sure don't want to share it with people.

See for yourself:

> [image]

Appears below questions without answers on the main site.

Comment: I don't see that; it says 'Facebook' in my browser, Chrome. What do you use to not see that? Any extensions enabled that might mess this up?

Comment: No repro in Chrome/Firefox...

Comment: Do you have some kind of something blocker?

Comment: Yeah, I see it with AdBlock Plus on Chrome.

Comment: That's not a bug but still, would be nice to find a workaround. Voting to reopen. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is caused by having AdBlock Plus (or similar) enabled. The HTML for the Facebook link *is* there in the source, but gets removed from the page via CSS by the following adblock rule:

```
a[href^="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?"]
```