# Remove Share to Twitter and Facebook-link

Tags: feature-request, facebook, twitter, sharing

- Twitter no longer exists. It is now called "X".
- These websites are a net negative on this planet; we should not promote them (and there is no way they can be used to promote Stack Exchange).
- Owners of both these sites are ehm, you know, evil.

Do you agree? Disagree? Please post your opinion in the answers/comments.

Comment: Not really, but I am glad to see others have similar ideas.

Comment: @cocomac that question is about profile links and unrestricting them. This FR is about *restricting* (or rather *removing*) [the share links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idKbt.png).

Comment: @VLAZ This sentence looks a bit weird on my PC: https://i.imgur.com/CRTHRHr.png

Comment: @Gantendo you have an addon which blocks these links.

Comment: See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196366/facebook-playing-hide-and-seek) about the missing links.

Comment: What do you mean by *"promote superuser"*? Can you elaborate? It may or may not be *"promote [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour)"* (this question from migrated from [Meta Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/)).

Comment: Add Mastodon!!!

Comment: Are we talking about the text which appears on [questions with no answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/258957). It seems that there were some experiment with this [in the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289217).

Comment: Semi-related MSO request: [Change Twitter name and icon to X on the profile page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425731/1478931)

Comment: FWIW, I don't think that this question is, strictly speaking, a duplicate of the User Profile question. However, I could see both questions being grouped under a more general question regarding Stack Exchange and social media sites.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think it ought to be less about the merits of their sites, and the people who manage or mismanage them, and more about utility

That said, having poked at how things work now... copy/pasting the link is a little easier than the buttons and it does add a certain level of obvious platform agnosticness.

I'd actually see this as a decent idea, especially if one of these services ends up in a death spiral

Comment: I think there are natural questions when it comes to utility: Why Facebook and Twitter? Why not LinkedIn, Reddit, and Hacker News? What factors lead to making it easy to share to one site and having to copy/paste the URL to share in another? Ultimately, all of this leads me to: Does it make sense to promote certain sites instead of a less cluttered visual interface or maybe a way to drop the user ID from the URL for private sharing?

Comment: On the subject of utility, I do not have a Twitter/X account but I am forced to log in when I follow a link from a newspaper website so the newspaper is acting as recruiter for X. This is not something SE should be doing.

Comment: How about replacing it with just a generic "share" Link that opens the device specific [sharing window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share)? That would feel like the best of both worlds (Having a sharing button while not having to update it when a site gets bought/nuked)

Comment: "especially if one of these services ends up in a death spiral" -- it seems both are well underway in death spirals. Hoping that SE has sense enough to avoid the same fate.

Comment: What if one of the buttons copied the link in markdown format? I'm usually sharing within SE (but people copying to Github or some other place with MD would probably also benefit).

Comment: @ThomasOwens I feel like there was a time when Facebook and Twitter were the only mainstream social media sites out there, and pretty much every site offered those two. I may be remembering incorrectly and that is not the case now, but that may have been the logic back when this started